# without the encode_plus method in tokenizers, how to make a feature matrix

Tags: huggingface-transformers, huggingface-tokenizers, huggingface

I am working on a low-resource language and need to make a classifier.
I used the tokenizers library to train the following tokenizers: WLV, BPE, UNI, WPC. I have saved the result of each into a json file.

I load each of the tokenizers using `Tokenizer.from_file` function.

```
tokenizer_WLV = Tokenizer.from_file('tokenizer_WLV.json')
```

and I can see it is loaded properly. However only the method `encode` exists.

so if I do `tokenizer_WLV.encode(s1)`, I get an output like

```
Encoding(num_tokens=7, attributes=[ids, type_ids, tokens, offsets, attention_mask, special_tokens_mask, overflowing]
```

and I can see each token along with the id as following.

```
out_wlv = tokenizer_WLV.encode(s1)
print(out_wlv.ids)
print(out_wlv.tokens)
```

I can use the `encode_batch`

```
def tokenize_sentences(sentences, tokenizer, max_seq_len = 128):
    tokenizer.enable_padding(pad_id=3, pad_token="[PAD]", direction='right')
    tokenized_sentences = tokenizer.encode_batch(sentences)
    return tokenized_sentences
```

which results in something like

```
[Encoding(num_tokens=40, attributes=[ids, type_ids, tokens, offsets, attention_mask, special_tokens_mask, overflowing]),
 Encoding(num_tokens=40, attributes=[ids, type_ids, tokens, offsets, attention_mask, special_tokens_mask, overflowing]),
 Encoding(num_tokens=40, attributes=[ids, type_ids, tokens, offsets, attention_mask, special_tokens_mask, overflowing]),
 Encoding(num_tokens=40, attributes=[ids, type_ids, tokens, offsets, attention_mask, special_tokens_mask, overflowing])]
```

I need to make a data feature in a size of mxn where m is the number of observations and n number of unique tokens. `encode_plus` does this automatically. So I am curious what is the most efficient way for constructing this feature matrix ?

Answer (score 0):

`encode_plus` is a method that huggingface transformer tokenizers have (but it is already deprecated and should therefore be ignored).

The alternative huggingface tokenizers and the huggingface transformer tokenizers provide is `__call__`:

```py
tokenizer_WLV(s1)
```